# Disable Ubuntu 16.04 boot on internal HD

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive

Having solved my external usb problem and now having a bootable ubuntu external HD I have one further hurdle.  My internal HD is failing but I still have some data to copy.  I am currently going into bios every time I boot to choose the external HD and I am sure if I forget and boot from the internal drive it could mess up the boot loader.  My laptop has no way to set boot device permanently - it defaults to the internal drive.  I was thinking maybe I could disable Ubuntu boot on the internal drive.  The goal is so the default drive becomes the external HD and if I forget to set it in bios then the internal will not boot, will not affect the external and my data remains in tact.

Making the internal default is ideal but if I forget to set external in bios and just get error message that is still acceptable as long as the external is not affected and will still boot again

Any ideas or advice please guys - thanks

Comment: "My laptop has no way to set boot device permanently , , ,"  Are you really SURE about that? Have you been through all of the bios settings? Looked closely at ALL  the tabs? I didn't know anybody made a bios with no facility to "save and exit". At any rate, if you think your drive is failing and you have data you really wouldn't want to lose, don't delay, don't spend time pursuing this until you've dealt with priority 1:  Back it up NOW.

Comment: @Lew Rockwell Fan - It seems I choose boot device and save and exit but next time the internal is highlighted again and there seems to be no way to define a boot sequence, but I will check again.  I am currently backing up everything but there will be a time when I boot and forget to set bios or bios has reset itself, same as it soes with disable secure boot every week or 2.  So my original question stands.  I really want to know how to disable Ubuntu boot on the internal so in the event of a mistake my external will not be affected.  Otherwise it is too much of a risk. But thanks very much.

Comment: I don't see how your external drive is threatened. Once you have the data off the internal drive, what's the harm (other than a couple of minutes lost while  you reboot) if you boot from the internal drive occasionally? So what if boot fails? Just reboot. Shouldn't matter beyond the annoyance. And once you have the data backed up, you can repartition it, reformat it, and run disk checking utitlities on it until the cows come home. It might be fixable in situ. And if it isn't, replacing  an internal drive is usually simple and reasonably cheap.

Comment: Also if it really doesn't retain the settings when you save, I wonder (and I'm past the edge of my knowledge and speculating here) if that might be a failing  battery. I don't mean the big battery that runs the laptop, but the little one that runs the clock. I think the non-volatile RAM that the bios settings  are stored on is "MOS-FET" if I remember correctly. Maybe that requires a tiny trickle of current? You might want to look that up. Probably not too hard to replace that either if it could be the issue. At any rate I wouldn't mess with this until your data is backed up. Reboot=risk.

Comment: @Lew Rockwell Fan - i have been told and have personal experience that when you have 2 drives both ubuntu bootable, booting from one can update the bootloader of the other drive, rendering it unbootable.  I created a bootable custom liveCD which worked fine, I then booted from the internal drive and from that point neither disk would boot.

Comment: @Lew Rockwell Fan - 'replacing an internal drive is usually simple and reasonably cheap' unfortunately not on an island 20km off the mainland of Cambodia, we don't even have hot water  :-)

Comment: Grub2 can do some strange things like that. I switched to lilo, partially because it is more under manual control.  Still, your data wouldn't be at risk. That would be an annoyance only - easily fixed if you have a live disk to work from. The boot information on your live CAN'T be overwritten. Anyway, you shouldn't be rebooting at all, until your data is backed up. And once it is, you can repartition and reformat the problematic drive. So I still can't see the relevance. The important thing is to finish the backup before you shutdown or reboot. And before you do anything else with that drive.

Comment: @Lew Rockwell Fan - That is my plan, I just need to be sure that after backup I can still boot from external otherwise even if data is safe I cannot get to it without reinstalling to external.  Yes I can use Live to reboot but it does not have all applications so I would need to re-install them all again - my question remains the same - how to prevent internal from booting ubuntu and just be a data drive.

Comment: @Lew Rockwell Fan - the other thing is backing up data before you reboot is obviously of prime importance - I appreciate that, but not all data is in one place.  I have to remember some data is in opt/lamp/htdocs also to do sql export of databases in xampp etc it is easy to forget something and my life will simply be easier if I can disable ubuntu boot on internal drive.... and then there is downloads....

Answer (score 0):

OK finally sorted it - delete Fat32 system partition from internal drive, data still intact and external is only bootable device so always boots from there - phew - long debates but simple answer - thanks for your input especially sudodus and Lew Rockwell Fan